# unordered_multimap - iterating the result of find() yields elements with different value

Tags: c++, c++11, stl, iteration, unordered-map

The multimap in C++ seems to work really odd, i would like to know why

```
#include <iostream>
#include <unordered_map>

using namespace std;

typedef unordered_multimap<char,int> MyMap;

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    MyMap map;
    map.insert(MyMap::value_type('a', 1));
    map.insert(MyMap::value_type('b', 2));
    map.insert(MyMap::value_type('c', 3));
    map.insert(MyMap::value_type('d', 4));
    map.insert(MyMap::value_type('a', 7));
    map.insert(MyMap::value_type('b', 18));

    for(auto it = map.begin(); it != map.end(); it++) {
        cout << it->first << '\t';
        cout << it->second << endl;
    }

    cout << "all values to a" << endl;
    for(auto it = map.find('a'); it != map.end(); it++) {
        cout << it->first << '\t' << it->second << endl;
    }

}
```

this is the output:

```
c   3
d   4
a   1
a   7
b   2
b   18
all values to a
a   1
a   7
b   2
b   18
```

why does the output still contain anything with b as the key when I am explicitly asking for 'a'? Is this a compiler or stl bug?

Answer (score 63, accepted):

`find`, as implemented, returns an iterator for the first element which matches the key in the multimap (as with any other map). You're likely looking for [`equal_range`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/equal_range):

```
// Finds a range containing all elements whose key is k.
// pair<iterator, iterator> equal_range(const key_type& k)
auto its = map.equal_range('a');
for (auto it = its.first; it != its.second; ++it) {
    cout << it->first << '\t' << it->second << endl;
}
```

Comment: Note that "find, as implemented, returns an iterator for the first element" is not guaranteed by the standard

Comment: I would definitely expect that find(key) == equal_range(key).first.

Answer (score 10):

That's not a bug, it is by design. `find` returns an iterator to one of the matching elements, that's all. You'll iterate to the end of the map with your construct.

You need to use [`multimap::equal_range`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/multimap/equal_range/) to do what you are after.

Answer (score 5):

There is an Example in [www.cplusplus.com](http://www.cplusplus.com) , about How to use equal_range method to get all elements having the same key.

```
// unordered_multimap::equal_range
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <unordered_map>
#include <algorithm>

typedef std::unordered_multimap<std::string,std::string> stringmap;

int main ()
{
  stringmap myumm = {
     {"orange","FL"},
     {"strawberry","LA"},
     {"strawberry","OK"},
     {"pumpkin","NH"}
  };

  std::cout << "Entries with strawberry:";
  auto range = myumm.equal_range("strawberry");
  for_each (
    range.first,
    range.second,
    [](stringmap::value_type& x){std::cout << " " << x.second;}
  );

  return 0;
}
```

Please reference the link : http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/unordered_map/unordered_multimap/equal_range/

Comment: @einpoklum This is **an answer** before deleting please read this meta [youre-doing-it-wrong-a-plea-for-sanity-in-the-low-quality-posts-queue](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/287563/youre-doing-it-wrong-a-plea-for-sanity-in-the-low-quality-posts-queue)

Comment: Let me rephrase that (the review mechanism doesn't let you make specific comments and you're choosing from a list): OP asked "Why does X happen?" - your answer, while possibly useful in general, is not an explanation of what happens with OP's code. So, not an answer.

Answer (score -1):

It would seem that you get an iterator into the full "list" of pairs, starting at the first pair with 'a' as it's key. So when you iterate to the end, naturally you will get everything beyond 'a' as well. If you sought for 'c', you would probably iterate through the entire "list" doing what you do there. Perhaps you should iterate to "it != map.end() && it->first == 'a'" if you want all the a's.