# Unordered multimap finding all values

Tags: c++, unordered-map, multimap

I would like to see whether it is possible to see all values that we have emplaced. For example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <unordered_map>

using namespace std;


int main () {
    unordered_multimap<string,int> hash;

    hash.emplace("Hello", 12);
    hash.emplace("World", 22);
    hash.emplace("Wofh", 25);
    for (int i = 1; i < 10; i++) {
        hash.emplace("Wofh", i);
    }
    cout << "Hello " << hash.find("Hello")->second << endl;
    cout << "Wofh " << hash.count("Wofh") << endl;
    cout << "Wofh " << hash.find("Wofh")->second << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

The output is :

```
$ ./stlhash
Hello 12
Wofh 10
Wofh 9
```

Whereas I want the last line to show from 25,1,2... to 9. Apparently `find` only takes `first` and `second` pointer as first is the value and second is the corresponding value. Is there any way to do this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [C++ unordered\_multimap](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9046922/c-unordered-multimap)

Answer (score 3):

The operation you need is called [equal_range](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/unordered_map/unordered_multimap/equal_range/)

Example from the cplusplus.com:

```
// unordered_multimap::equal_range
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <unordered_map>
#include <algorithm>

typedef std::unordered_multimap<std::string,std::string> stringmap;

int main ()
{
  stringmap myumm = {
     {"orange","FL"},
     {"strawberry","LA"},
     {"strawberry","OK"},
     {"pumpkin","NH"}
  };

  std::cout << "Entries with strawberry:";
  auto range = myumm.equal_range("strawberry");
  for_each (
    range.first,
    range.second,
    [](stringmap::value_type& x){std::cout << " " << x.second;}
  );

  return 0;
}
```