# How would one look for entities with specific components in an entity component system?

Tags: c++, game-engine

How would one look for entities with specific components in an entity component system?

In my current implementation I'm storing components in a 
    `std::unordered_map< entity_id, std::unordered_map<type_index, Component *> >`.

So if a system needs access to entities with specific components, what is the most efficient way to access them.

I currently have 2 ideas:

1. Iterate through the map and skip the entities that don't have those components.
2. Create "mappers" or "views" that hold a pointer to the entity and update them every time a component is assigned to or removed from an entity.

I saw some approaches with bitmasks and such, but that doesn't seem scalable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your situation calls for std::unordered_multimap.

"find" method would return an iterator for the first element, which matches the key in multimap. "equal_range" method would return you a pair, containing the iterators for the first and last object, matching your key.

Actually what unordered_multimap allows you to create is an in-memory key-value database that stores a bunch of objects for the same key.

If your "queries" would get more complicated than "give me all objects with component T" and turn into something like "give me all components that have component T and B at the same time", you would be better suited to create a class that has unordered_multimap as a member and has a bunch of utility methods for querying the stuff.

More on the subject:

- http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/unordered_map/unordered_multimap/equal_range/
- [unordered_multimap - iterating the result of find() yields elements with different value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9046922/c-unordered-multimap) (somewhat related question - the accepted answer could be helpful)

Comment: I already have what is basically a wrapper around an `std::unordered_map` that adds, removes and retrieves components from that map (and entities are ids in the map), so what you're suggesting would just be changing a data type and a few functions. Perfect!

Answer (score 0):

The way I do it involves storing a back index to the entity from the component (32-bits). It adds a bit of memory overhead but the total memory overhead of a component in mine is around 8 bytes which is usually not too bad for my use cases, and around 4 bytes per entity.

Now when you have a back index to an entity, what you can do when satisfying a query for all entities that have 2 or more component types is to use parallel bit sets.

For example, if you are looking for entities with two component types, `Motion`, and `Sprite`, then we start out by iterating through the motion components and set the associated bits for the entities that own them.

Next we iterate through the sprite components and look for the entity bits already set by the pass through motion components. If the entity index appears in both the motion components and the sprite components, then we add the entity to the list of entities that contain both. A diagram of the idea as well as how to multithread it and pool the entity-parallel bit arrays:

[image]

That gives you a set intersection in linear time and with a very small `m` (very, very cheap work per iteration as we're just marking and inspecting a bit -- much, much, much cheaper than a hash table, e.g.). I can actually perform a set intersection between two sets with 100 million elements each in under a second using this technique. As a bonus, with some minor effort, you can make it give you the entities back in sorted order for cache-friendly access patterns if you use the bitset to grab the indices of the entities that belong in 2 or more components.

There are ways to do this in better than linear time (`Log(N)/Log(64)`) though it gets considerably more involved where you can actually perform a set intersection between two sets containing a hundred million elements each in under a millisecond. Here's a hint:

[image]